# Is it possible to increase the speed of the RPi peripherals?

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi

I have not tested all the peripherals of the Raspberry Pi 4, only the serial port. Reading a register with modbus (6 bytes) takes 6 ms, while if I do the same with a microcontroller it takes 50 us. Are all the peripherals of the raspberry always slower?

Probably the peripherals are not the bad ones, but the operating system of the Raspberry.  Is there any method to improve the response speed?

Comment: Maybe you are using them wrong, or with wrong language? Do you write your code in Python, C, Java, assembly or something else?

Comment: im using python

Comment: So you are writing with an interpreted language and then complaining about slowness? Or maybe the serial port setup for timeouts is wrong. Impossible to say without seeing the code really.

Comment: No. The difference is a lot, between 50us to 10 ms there are more than two orders of magnitude! between python and C there is a lot of difference but not so much

Comment: The problem is not the peripheral itself. It is the driver, and how the OS runs the driver and your code, and also how the pyserial module works internally, and how your code uses pyserial for transmitting and receiving. Do you ever flush transmit buffers for immediate transmit? How about the receive handling? Or do you simply use pyserial defaults?

Comment: So did you try accessing the peripheral with a C program instead? (Using native Linux syscalls and buffer flushing, not some kind of serial library.)

Comment: let me try with c, i will return later

Comment: Speed is one thing, but it's primarily the latency and its variance that can be expected to be higher from Linux user code compared to bare metal.

Comment: As @DamienD mentions, if your program is executing as an application layer process, AND you are using a "stock" Linux OS that does not provide support for real-time process scheduling, then your program will experience nondeterministic latencies, even if the program is compiled (e.g., a C/C++ program).  This is unavoidable.

Comment: @Justme On my raspi4, I can do almost 3mln simple reads per second in Python, that's 300ns per read. OP is complaining about 6ms, 4 orders of magnitude slower. Dismissing his question with "Python is slow" is not very helpful here; Python is likely not the problem. By the way, Python is compiled into bytecode which is run in a VM. I wouldn't call it "interpreted".

Comment: I’d suggest it is a design feature of the library. The challenge with Modbus RTU is detecting the end of the message. The timeout is probably a little more generous than the 3 char times per the spec. The response times of PLCs i’ve found is generally slow anyway as the response is done per program cycle which can be many milliseconds. With the devices I wrote, the response was to the spec.

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro You'll have to provide a lot more information than you have now; what are you trying to do exactly? What are your serial port settings? How are things connected? How are you doing the timing? Is serial communication fast with other devices? Show a minimum working example of your code. In my (limited) experience, modbus devices can be pretty temperamental, sometimes giving slow responses when they don't like _something_. Cable reflections can be quite the issue. Rpi peripherals are generally OK; I wouldn't pin such high latency on them as a first guess.